# Compare a character in a string with a letter?

Tags: java, replace, char, compare

I want to compare a character in a string with the letter "R". So I want to check if the character on the position `i` in the string is a "R", a "L" or a "F".

This is my code, but it doesn't word...
I'm a Java beginner and really happy about every idea to improve my code and makes it work.

```
        for (int i = s.length()-2; i >= 0; i--){
            if (s.charAt(i) == "R"){
                    s = s + "L";}
            else if (s.charAt(i) == L){
                    s = s + "R";}
            else {s = s + "F";}
```

//      s = s + s.charAt(i);
        }//for

By the way, the complete exercise is to get a random string (for example RFFLF), to add a R and then to add the given string in the turned around order and replace (in the added string) every R with L and every L with R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you must be careful with your types. `s.charAt(i)` returns a `char` type (not that surprising given the name of the method), but you're comparing it with a `String` `"R"`. That won't compile and even if it did, it wouldn't work; chars and String are different beasts and are never equal.

`char` literals are delimited by *single* quotes, eg `'R'`.

This code is what I think you're tying to code:

```
String result = "";
if (s.charAt(i) == 'R') {
    result = result + "L"; // you could code + 'L' too - both will work
}
```

Note that your attempt at modifying the original String won't work either. Use a new String as per my code. Much easier to understand and get right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't used java before, so I'm a real beginner. The problem that s.charAt(i) is a char and not a string sounds logical ;) I don't know why I haven't think about this before :) While I've tried to solfe the problem I've found an other way to make the program work. I've compared the s.charAt(i) with (char)85 (85 is the Ascii number of "R"). It works too and now the program modifies the original string.

Comment: @dino1995 no problem. `(char)85` is identical in effect to `'R'`, but we all know which is easier to read.

Comment: Okay, I think I've understand the difference between "R" and 'R' now :) thank you :)